# Android - Get auto suggest on top of keyboard for EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I need edittext with auto suggestion turned on.
For this I am using following in xml :

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_description"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/description_album_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_light_gray" />
```

Even if I add "textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete" as inputType still there are no suggestions.

Adding Screenshot (this is what I need to implement): 
[image]

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default suggestion on so no worry about on suggestion.

Comment: Do you want auto complete text in your edit text??

Comment: I think you need to use `AutocompleteTextView`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: added screenshot. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need a subclass of EditText called AutoCompleteTextView. You can find an example here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get auto suggestions in top of your keypad, what ever you are following is correct. Additionally you can add `android:autoText="true"`. The suggestion will show you all your previously entered words.

Else if you want to get suggestion for every letter you type, then you can use   `AutoCompleteTextView`.
Here is the code, how you can use this.[Ex - AutoCompleteTextView](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html)

Comment: android:autoText is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Got it .....
just removing "textAutoComplete" from "textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete" worked for me.